# Show pop-up where user clicked in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, line, popup

How to change this example ( http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-openpopup.html ) so that when the user clicks on a line (feature) pop-up display where the user clicked? A few days trying to do it, does not work.

My code (alert doesnt show when i clicked on feature (line)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var lat=48.5;
            var lon=32.24;
            var zoom=14;
            var map;
            var drawControls, selectControl, selectedFeature;
            var CableLineText_arr = Array();
            var ClickLon;
            var ClickLat;

            OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {                
                defaultHandlerOptions: {
                    'single': true,
                    'double': false,
                    'pixelTolerance': 0,
                    'stopSingle': false,
                    'stopDouble': false
                },

                initialize: function(options) {
                    this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                        {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
                    );
                    OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
                        this, arguments
                    ); 
                    this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
                        this, {
                            'click': this.trigger
                        }, this.handlerOptions
                    );
                }, 

                trigger: function(e) {
                    var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
                    lonlat.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
                    alert("You clicked near " + lonlat.lat + " N, " +
                                              + lonlat.lon + " E");
                    ClickLon = lonlat.lon;
                    ClickLat = lonlat.lat;                  
                }

            });


            function onPopupClose(evt) {
                selectControl.unselect(selectedFeature);
            }
            function onFeatureSelect(feature) {         
                selectedFeature = feature;
                id = feature.id;
                var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(ClickLon, ClickLat)/*.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"))*/;
                popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
                                        lonLat,
                                        null,
                                        "<div style='font-size:.8em'>" +CableLineText_arr[id]  +"</div>",
                                        null, true, onPopupClose);
                feature.popup = popup;
                map.addPopup(popup);
            }
            function onFeatureUnselect(feature) {
                map.removePopup(feature.popup);
                feature.popup.destroy();
                feature.popup = null;
            }

            function init() {
                map = new OpenLayers.Map({
                    div: "map",
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    controls:[
                    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition()
                    ],
                units: "m",
                allOverlays: true
                });

                var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
                var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets", {visibility: false});

                map.addLayers([osm, gmap]);

    //
                var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line Layer"); 
                map.addLayer(lineLayer);                    
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path));

                var style = { 
                    strokeColor: 'blue',
                    strokeOpacity: 5.5,
                    strokeWidth: 5
                };

                var points = new Array(
                    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(32, 47.5),    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(32.2, 48.5),  new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(33, 49)
                );
                var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);
                line.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
                var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style);
                lineLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);
                CableLineText_arr[lineFeature.id]='Имя: test<br>Комментарий: for testing map';
                selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(lineLayer,
                    {onSelect: onFeatureSelect, onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect});

                /*drawControls = {
                    polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer,
                                OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
                    select: selectControl
                };*/
                drawControls = {
                    point: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer,
                                OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
                    select: selectControl
                };

                for(var key in drawControls) {
                    map.addControl(drawControls[key]);
                }

    //

                map.addControls(
                [
                    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Click
                ]
                );
                var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
                map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);   
            }
        function toggleControl(element) {
            for(key in drawControls) {
                var control = drawControls[key];
                if(element.value == key && element.checked) {
                    control.activate();
                } else {
                    control.deactivate();
                }
            }
        }

        </script>
```

Help me. Thanks!

Comment: This may help anyone look for that.
Try using `evt.xy`,
for location. It works for me:)

Comment: Would you please provide more detail of how to implement this? You can edit your answer to do so.

Comment: please i want to know if this probleme was solved, i have the same probleme

Answer (score 1):

it seemed to me as a little bit confused... try to use this example [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html).

still u insist the code above, paste the http://jsfiddle.net/ so i can write a solution for u...

i hope it helps you...

Comment: what fieddle.net? I need when I click on line at the point where I clicked, there show a pop-up. If slightly change the function onFeatureSelect and change "lonLat," to "feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat()," getting this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YH6TfsG8iXs&feature=youtu.be A popup window appears, not where I clicked!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. In function onFeatureSelect(feature) need change that string:

```
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(ClickLon, ClickLat)/*.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"))*/;
```

to:

```
var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(map.getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition")[0].lastXy);
```

Ie obtain the coordinates of the cursor position.