# Problem with popup conclusion on pressing a marker

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2

I have markers on pressing to which popup has to be brought. how to make it? (coordinates of markers undertake from a DB)

```
var map;
var markers;


function ejecutar() {
    init(3);
    //loadMarkers();
}
function init(b,kor_1,kor_2) {
    if (b == 3) {
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap", {
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()],
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34),
            maxResolution: 156543.0399,
            numZoomLevels: 2,
            units: 'm',
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        });
    }

    layerMapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("MapaCiudad");
    map.addLayer(layerMapnik);
    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(50.5206298828125, 55.15881723298661).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
    //map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-3.862788677215576, 43.4669443349282) // Center of the map
    map.zoomTo(9);
    map.setCenter(lonLat, 19);


    //создаем дорогу

    var lineLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Линии"); 
    map.addLayer(lineLayer);                    
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path));

    var points = new Array(
       new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(37.61556, 55.75222),
       new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(45, 33),
       new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(49, 35),
       new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(45, 56),
       new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(49, 87)
    );

    var line = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points);
    line.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));

    var style = { 
        strokeColor: '#0000ff', 
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWidth: 5
    };

    var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(line, null, style);
    lineLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);


    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
             "popup",
             OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
             null,
             '<div style="color:#FF0000">'+feature.data.Name + '</br><a href="http://test.url">test.url</a>' + '</div>',
             null,
             true
         );

    //добавление на карту 
    map.addPopup(popup, true);



    //создаем маркер
    markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Marcadores");
    map.addLayer(markers);

    if (b == 2) 
    {           

            //=================  =========стили для маркеров и тут хранятся координаты
            var size = new OpenLayers.Size(30, 30);
            var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -size.h);

            var location = new OpenLayers.LonLat(kor_1, kor_2).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/256/Map-Marker-Ball-Pink-icon.png', size, offset);
            markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(location, icon.clone()));





    }


}
```

```
    function add_metka()
    {
        function dobavit(koor1, koor2)
        {

            init(2,koor1,koor2);
        }


    @foreach (Дорожное_строительство.Models.koordinats_piket picket  in ViewBag.Data)
    {
    <text>
        dobavit(@picket.Dolgota,@picket.Shirota);       
    </text>
    }

    }

    setTimeout('add_metka()', 6000)
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you need, en espanhol mejor? =)

Comment: from russia)by pressing a marker to make the popup.how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was spanish because you have "Marcadores". Anyway check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32229/customizing-popups-in-openlayers), basically you need:

```
var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                "popup",
                OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
                null,
                '<div style="color:#FF0000">'+feature.data.Name + '</br><a href="http://test.url">test.url</a>' + '</div>',
                null,
                true
            );
```

Comment: i add this code.....no work..((((Maybe to this code still it is necessary to add something?

Comment: post your whole code, in that way is easier to see what is your problem

Comment: I edited the code. (I added the whole code)

Comment: you need to modify the popup according to your code, the example above is just an example, I think your problem is feature.geometry.toShortString(), for more examples check [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28748/show-pop-up-where-user-clicked-in-openlayers)

Comment: markers.events.register("click", markers, function(e){
                    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup("chicken",
                                    map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.x),
                                    new OpenLayers.Size(200,200),
                                    "example popup",
                                    true);

                    map.addPopup(popup);
                });